# How to make bash aliases available as linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, alias

I have many bash aliases on a remote location.
But when I try to run those from my local linux box,
I get the 'command not found' error. e.g.

```
$ ssh root@remote 'status'  
bash: status: command not found
```

On the remote location, status is defined as

```
$ alias status='ls /tmp/status'
```

How can I declare an alias on the remote location,
such that I can invoke it from any location?

Comment: What's an m/c ?

Answer (score 1):

See the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/424030/134295) to a similar question on Server Fault. Basically, bash doesn't expand aliases in non-interactive shells unless explicitly configured to do so (`shopt -s expand_aliases`). Plus, you have to make sure that `.bashrc` is evaluated even in non-interactive shells.

Comment: I would recommend putting the aliases in a separate file, which you can source from `.bashrc` and source explicitly when logging into the remote host.

Comment: In general good practice, but unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
ssh root@remote_mc 'bash -ic status'
```

To run another copy of the shell in interactive mode (which means it'll load the aliases from your bash configuration files)

Starting a second shell isn't that fantastic a solution, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if you want to create many aliases, best solution is:

- Create a hidden file (I called it `.bash_aliases`) in your `/home/"user_name"`
- In this file you have to put all the aliases that you want to use in terminal. I.e mine is:

> alias ll='ls -l'
>
> alias la='ls -A'
>
> alias mydu='du -s * .[^.]* | sort -n'
>
> alias apti='sudo apt-get install'
>
> alias aptr='sudo apt-get remove'
>
> alias aptu='sudo apt-get update'
>
> alias aptg='sudo apt-get upgrade'
>
> alias down='sudo ifconfig wlan0 down'
>
> alias up='sudo ifconfig wlan0 up'
>
> alias managed='sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed'
>
> alias monitor='sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor'
>
> alias usb='sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt'

- In your `/home/"user_name"/.bashrc` file, put the following lines:

> # More alias definitions in ~/.bash_aliases
>
> if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ];
>   then
>   . ~/.bash_aliases
>   fi

I put this line in the end of the file, but just for clarity.

Comment: Why the downvote ?????

Comment: Probably cause your answer has nothing to do with the original question...